# Принять к руководству в работе

Tags: грамотная-речь

*Грамотно ли составлена фраза: **"Принять к руководству в работе"**?*

Answer (score 1):

РУКОВОДСТВО, 2. То, чем руководствуются или следует руководствоваться.

**Принять к руководству в работе.**  Грамматически фраза составлена верно, в качестве краткой резолюции (без подробностей) можно использовать.

На документе обычно делается отметка «Принять к руководству и исполнению». Или: Принять постановление к руководству.

В других случаях указывается вид деятельности, например: При планировании и проведении артиллерийского наступления **принять к руководству** следующее.

Answer (score 1):

[Принять к руководству в работе].

Фраза построена неверно. Ср.: ***Принять (использовать) как руководство к действию.***

ИЛИ:  ***Принять как руководство в работе.***

Comment: К сожалению, Ваш ответ не аргументирован. "Принять к руководству" - нормативное употребление. Тогда почему "Принять к руководству в работе" - неверно?

Comment: Принять к руководству - всего 18 примеров в нацкорпусе. Канцеляризм. На мой взгляд, ошибочная перефразировка известного выражения "принять к сведению", смешение его с выражением "принять как руководство к действию". Впрочем, Вы правы: надо искать солидный источник информации для приведения доказательств.

Answer (score 0):

Фраза неверная.
"Принять к руководству" можно что-либо только в смысле "возглавить", "начать руководить". А не руководствоваться. Но тогда и не "в работе".

Откуда такое взялось, не берусь судить. Скорее уж от "принять к исполнению". При том, что Екатерина Каштанова в одном, видимо, права. Канцеляпизм.

Comment: @М_Г  Вы, возможно, не поняли. Или меня, или Екатерину, на которую я ссылаюсь. "Принять к руководству" это вполне приемлемо как канцеляризм (не всякий же канцеляризм ненормативен вообще!), но не в сочетании  с "в работе". Хотя... Не знаю... Для Николая такая резолюция действительно не выглядит неестественно. Он же руководитель как-никак. "Из всех пышных оборотов царского режима" очень мало таких, которые были позаимствованы  большевиками и сохранили при этом исходный смысл. Здесь явно не тот случай.

Comment: В наше время канцеляризм "принять к рукoводству" употребляется в смысле "начать руководствоваться", а не в смысле "начать рукoводить" . Если вы считаете, что "принять к рукoводству" =  "начать руководить", то должны признать современное употребление этого канцеляризмa неверным, даже без слов "в работе". А если вы допускаете применение его в смысле "начать руководствоваться", то почему не признать верным и "принять к рукoводству  в работе" в смысле "начать руководствоваться в работе"?

Comment: *Если вы считаете, что "принять к рукoводству" = "начать руководить"* - я не в состоянии понять ваш силлогизм. Я говорил о том, что "принять к руководству" можно, например, завод. А что  хотел сказать Николай, я не очень понимаю без контекста. Скорее всего "начать управлять" (в соответствии с документом). Другими словами, "я хотел сказать", что здесь оттенки значения, которые нам сейчас непонятны, но они скорее всего связаны с положением в обществе фигуры, которая такую резолюцию наложила. Но в любом сочетание "с работой"  превращает оборот или в бессмыслицу, или в тавтологию.